# string regular expression algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm

I am reading string algorithms in Robert Sedgewick.

Here is a text snippet about regular expressions from the book.

> In many applications, we need to do substring searching with somewhat
>   less than complete information about the pattern to be found.
>
> A user of a text editor may wish
>       i. to specify only part of a pattern, or
>          ii. to specify a pattern that could match a few different words, or
>         iii.  to specify that any one of the number of patterns would do.

My question is what does author mean with the above three wishes. I am looking for an example for each of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the author is talking about when you what to search for a piece of data, but you have incomplete information about the data. If you do not have full information ,you cannot search for it literally, you have to use some kind of pattern to match the data. By rules and not by the data itself.

ex: if you know that there is the date of today present in the file, you have all the information, so you can search for `2015-10-16`. But if you have incomplete information, some pattern must be applied.

1. to specify only part of a pattern

you know that there is a date of this year, but don't know the day or month (incomplete information), you must be able to specify a pattern with the part of information you have `2015-*-*`.

2. to specify a pattern that could match a few different words

you know that there is a date of this decade but don't know the year, day or month you must be able to specify a pattern `20*-*-*` (notice that the part `20*` will match different "words" 2001,2002,...)

3. to specify that any one of the number of patterns would do.

you know that there is a date of this this year or the previous but don't know then rest. a pattern could be like `2014-*-*|2015-*-*`, this provides alternatives in the matching.

I don't think that the examples the author gives cover all the possibilities, but what he is trying to convey is that when you don't have all the information, you must be able to use the information that you have to create a pattern with rules, that allow you to gather the rest of the information (the days), while still respecting the information that you have(years) in several ways partially or alternatively